# Hibernate transaction validation / Object priority

Tags: java, hibernate, mariadb

Imagine the following scenario:

One table with topics, predecessor is linked to the same table / object:

```
 |ID | PREDECESSOR | DESCRIPTION |
 +---+-------------+-------------|
 | 1 | NULL        | Topic 1     |
 | 2 | 1           | Topic 2     |
 | 3 | 2           | Topic 3     |
```

Column Predecessor has a unique constraint, because one topic can only be the predecessor of one topic.

Now we delete Topic 2 in our application. To achieve this we have to objects:

```
 |ID | PREDECESSOR | DESCRIPTION |
 +---+-------------+-------------|
 | 2 | 1           | Topic 2       -> deleted
 | 3 | 1           | Topic 3       -> new predecessor, because 2 was deleted
```

Now we save these objects within one transaction:

```
....
PersistentTransaction trans = session.beginTransaction();
session.saveOrUpdate(object topic 3);
session.delete(object topic 2); //object order does not matter
trans.commit();
```

Hibernate Log:

```
Hibernate: 
update
    TOPIC
set
   .....
```

As you can see, unfortunately the update of topic 3 is called before deletion of topic 2 causing a

```
SqlException "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME'
```

This exception is clear, but if the order would be "delete topic 2" and afterwards "update topic 3" everything would be fine.

Why is this constrained checked in the middle of the transaction? In my mind the whole transaction should be valid and the validations should run at the end of the transaction. Am I unaware of something?

It´s possible to recreate this priority problem with many other scenarios, so it is clear that there can´t be a strict order like "deletions first, then modifications, etc...". Or maybe it´s a matter of adjustment in the db?
Can somebody give me a helping hand on this?

Hibernate 4.2.4;
MariaDb 10.1.25

Comment: Are the statements in the same transaction?

Comment: Yes they are, this is what i'm wondering about.

Comment: How do you delete topic2. session.saveOrUpdate saves or updates. use session.remove do delete. Does PREDECESSOR column have both unique and foreigin key checks?

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I use session.delete(topic2) - I will modify my example. Yes, PREDECESSOR has unique constraint and foreign key check.

Answer (score 0):

### Error Message:

> Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry ‘%s’ for key %d

**Example:**

> Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry ‘1’ for key ‘PRIMARY’

### Possible Reason:

**Case 1: Duplicate value.**

The data you are trying to insert is already present in the column primary key. The primary key column is unique and it will not accept the duplicate entry.

**Case 2: Unique data field.**

You are trying to add a column to an existing table which contains data and set it as unique.

**Case 3: Data type –upper limit.**

The auto_increment field reached its maximum range.

---

### Solution:

**Case 1: Duplicate value.**

Set the primary key column as AUTO_INCREMENT.

```
ALTER TABLE ‘table_name’ ADD ‘column_name’ INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Now, when you are trying to insert values, ignore the primary key column. Also you can insert NULL value to primary key column to generate sequence number. If no value specified MySQL will assign sequence number automatically.

**Case 2: Unique data field.**

Create the new column without the assigning it as unique field, then insert the data and now set it as unique field now. It will work now!!!

**Case 3: Data type-upper limit.**

When the data type reached its upper limit, for example, if you were assigned your primary key column as TINYINT, once the last record is with the id 127, when you insert a new record the id should be 128. But 128 is out of range for TINYINT so MySQL reduce it inside the valid range and tries to insert it with the id 127, therefore it produces the duplicate key error.

In order to solve this, you can alter the index field, setting it into signed / unsigned INT/ BIGINT depending on the requirement, so that the maximum range will increase. You can do that by using the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE ‘table_name’ MODIFY ‘column_name’ INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

You can use the following function to retrieve the most recently automatically generated AUTO_INCREMENT value:

> mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

---

### Final workaround:

After applying all the above mentioned solutions and still if you are facing this error code: 1062 Duplicate entry error, you can try the following workaround.

**Step 1: Backup database:**

You can backup your database by using following command:

> mysqldump database_name > database_name.sql

**Step 2: Drop and recreate database:**

Drop the database using the following command:

```
DROP DATABASE database_name;
```

Create the database using the following command:

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name;
```

**Step 3: Import database:**

You can import your database by using following command:

```
mysql database_name < database_name.sql;
```

After applying this workaround, the duplicate entry error will be solved. I hope this post will help you to understand and solve the MySQL Error code: 1062. Duplicate entry error. If you still facing this issue, you can contact me through the contact me page. I can help you to solve this issue.

Resource Link: http://www.rathishkumar.in/2016/01/how-to-solve-mysql-error-code-1062.html

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply to the sql-exception, but this is not what I was looking for. If hibernate would first delete the object and afterwards update the other one, there would be no problem. This was just a simple example for my question about object priorities within transactions. - I will edit my post and hope to become more clear